# [Google Colaboratory]: Why can't I use and import a module/package after installing it from Github?

Tags: github, module, python-import, google-colaboratory, importerror

I installed the [ismrmrd-python-tools](https://github.com/ismrmrd/ismrmrd-python-tools) succesfully after running the following command on Colab:

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/ismrmrd/ismrmrd-python-tools.git
```

> Successfully built ismrmrd-python-tools

But when I want to import the module, I get the next message error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ismrmrd'

I tried with other module names like 'ismrmrd-python-tools', 'ismrmrdtools', etc. as well.

Does someone know anything about what could possibly be happening here?

Answer (score 0):

I try it and it works without any problems.

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/ismrmrd/ismrmrd-python-tools.git
import ismrmrdtools
```